# Fancytooltip error during fancy-preview

Tags: miktex, texlive, perl, fancytooltips

I wanted to try the [fancytooltips](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips?lang=en) package. I did the installation according to [this page](http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/). I installed `perl` and the required `Config::IniFiles` library. I tried the installation both on Fedora using Texlive 2016 and on Windows 7 using MikTeX. The error is the same when calling the perl-script `fancy-preview` in this way: `perl fancy-preview myfile`

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.526 \pdfximage{\TooltipFilename
                                 .pdf}%
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.526 \pdfximage{\TooltipFilename
                                 .pdf}%
```

Related to this, warning was thrown:

```
Package fancytooltips Warning: ** The filename with tooltips is not given. ** on input line 198.
```

I tried it for hours, in vain. Here is my minimal (non-)working example (`myfile.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancytooltips}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
       x^2 + y^2 = 1
       \label{eq:circleEquation}
    \end{equation}

    Test the link: \eqref{eq:circleEquation}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fancytooltips` package must be called with the `inactive` option. Then it compiles.

Comment: Yeah, but does it produce tooltips then?..

Comment: Yes, it does. You have to use the provided perl script.