# How to use fancytooltips with MikTeX?

Tags: fancytooltips

I'm trying to create a tooltip with the `fancytooltips` package, the compilation is going well, but I don't get any tooltips.

I'm on Windows 7 with MikTeX.  I don't know if this is really necessary, but I installed PERL http://www.activestate.com/activeperl with the `Config::IniFiles` module.
I created the file `test-tip.pdf` containing a rectangle triangle created with tikz with this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,3)--(0,0)--(4,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Then, I compiled the main file with the "inactive" option as indicated in this thread: [Fancytooltip error during fancy-preview](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340577/fancytooltip-error-during-fancy-preview) because otherwise the compilation fails with this error:

> LaTeX Warning: File `fancytipmark. pdf' not found on input line 5. !
>   Package pdftex. def Error: File fancytipmark. pdf not found: using
>   draft sett

The main file is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[filename=test-tip,movetips,mouseover]{fancytooltips}

\begin{document}
Le \tooltip{triangle rectangle}1
\end{document}
```

- What should I correct in my code?
- How do I also get a simple text tooltip?

Comment: For simple tooltips, this [↗approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186) might do perhaps. Example on [↗ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59d28477c9c1ae088c59b29a).

Comment: Yes, indeed, for simple tooltips, it works very well. And being able to move tooltips is just great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found this `fancytipmark.pdf` file that is not included natively in MikTeX.  It is included in the compressed folder that can be downloaded from CTAN's fancytooltips page, here 
 http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancytooltips.zip

By including this file or indicating its path, as indicated by the author of the  package ( @robert.marik.cz ) in his answer, the compilation works without needing the `inactive` option and the tooltip is now visible.

By creating a fancytooltips folder in my local texmf folder according to the tree structure:

> local-texmf -> tex -> latex -> fancytooltips

in which I placed all the `fancytipmark.pdf` files (there are several of them), then refreshing the MikTeX database:

> MIKTEX Settings (Admin) -> Refresh FNDB

there is no need to specify the path to the `fancytipmark.pdf` files.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that LaTeX cannot find the file fancytipmark.pdf . You should set the path to this file or put the file somewhere in the LaTeX path.

btw: The approach used in fancytooptips package is overcomplicated. It worked well when the package was created, but the situation is different today. I agree with AlexG that there are better methods nowadays.

Comment: Thank you very much. Where can I find the file fancytipmark. pdf?